# Rails Permission Error on Sub-URI with Passenger, Apache, & Centos

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, centos6, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have a rails 4 application installed on a machine running centos 6. I have Apache serving up another application and I'm try to mount the rails application at a sub-uri. To aid deployment I've installed passenger. Below is my main httpd configuration file:

```
#CKAN
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

#RAILS Passenger
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@ohana-api/gems/passenger-4.0.50/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so

<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@ohana-api/gems/passenger-4.0.50
 PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@ohana-api/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>


<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
    ServerName xyz.clacksweb.org.uk
    ServerAlias xyz.clacksweb.org.uk
    WSGIScriptAlias / /etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi

    # Pass authorization info on (needed for rest api).
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    # Deploy as a daemon (avoids conflicts between CKAN instances).
    WSGIDaemonProcess ckan_default display-name=ckan_default processes=2 threads=15

    WSGIProcessGroup ckan_default

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ckan_default.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ckan_default.custom.log combined


    #RAILS PASSENGER STUFF
    DocumentRoot /home/ohana/repos/ohana-api/public
    <Directory /home/ohana/repos/ohana-api/public/>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
      # Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # These have been added:
    Alias /ohana /home/ohana/repos/ohana-api/public
    <Location /ohana>
      PassengerBaseURI /ohana
      PassengerAppRoot /home/ohana/repos/ohana-api
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I access the /ohana sub-uri I get a 403 Forbidden error: "You don't have permission to access /ohana/ on this server."

I've tried switching owner & group from the ohana user to root and back again for the application. What else should I be checking?

Comment: Check your `/var/log/audit/audit.log` of course.

Comment: Regarding your issue check whether selinux is enforcing by turning it off **sudo setenforce 0** **getenforce**

Comment: Good call, setenforce 0 & restarted httpd, but still no luck.